# Load Balancers scaling non web server applications

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I need to clarify about a very basic usage of Load Balancers such as Elastic Load Balancer of AWS. I have an Restlet application that exposes a REST api but it does not run inside any web server like tomcat. It runs as a standalone java process.

So will the load balancer be able to scale this application or the application has to be a web server application.

Comment: Off-topic; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [AWS Elastic Load Balancing Developers Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html) -

> Elastic Load Balancing supports the load balancing of applications
>   using HTTP, HTTPS (secure HTTP), TCP, and SSL (secure TCP) protocols.
>   The HTTPS uses the SSL protocol to establish secure connections over
>   the HTTP layer. You can also use SSL protocol to establish secure
>   connections over the TCP layer.
>
> The acceptable ports for both HTTPS/SSL and HTTP/TCP connections are
>   25, 80, 443, and 1024-65535.

So, as long as your service uses HTTP or HTTPS on one of those ports you can use it - it doesn't matter whether it is provided by a web server, an application server or a stand-alone process